# Why the Windowbox effect used on Oscar award show?

Tags: plot-explanation, mank

At the end of the *Mank* (2020) movie, the Windowbox effect used on
Oscar award show:

[image]

Why the Windowbox effect used on Oscar award show?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Everything has been compressed and made to sound like the 1940s.

Like the [cue marks](https://movies.stackexchange.com/q/119332/53946), it's intended to make the image look old. As this time, many movies were part of an entire show, with cartoons, news and more. I remember news being black and white in 4:3 format, so we could also see that stamp border around the screen.

Here are some pictures from the movie, with the same characteristics:

[image]
[image]
[image]